# Facebook bot & user access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a small bot with my facebook app.

I've an Facebook app, people registered to my app through facebook.

I want my bot to check every day checkins of my users (launch with scheduler like cron)

since the bot is not accessed by a user, is there any way to retrieve access token for a user to get checkins information? via graph api?

I read that access_token expires, event offline_token can not be used forever.

I have tried to store fb_uid and user code generated when registering, but that is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where offline_access rights are for. You can test this by using the token [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Just get a token with offline_access and you will see that the token won't ever expire. Until off course the rights are revoked by the user.

Comment: Hey, thanks! i'll try the offline_access and test all scenarios, i wish there was something like Foursquare API, u got a user access token and store it, then, u can access user checkins using his/her token....  regards, Adrien